# Angular 8 firebase push notification is not working when application is in foreground

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following this document to implement the FCM on my Angular web application. When I send the notification it receives successfully when the application is not active. ( Recieve background notifications ). But if the application is active, I'm not getting the notification.

Following these steps: https://dev.to/mayurkadampro/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-97a

basically this is not triggering when there is a new message

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload) => {
    console.log("new message received. ", payload);
    this.currentMessage.next(payload);})
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to trigger it manually.

When you receive you only logging it, and let the message go to the next one:

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload) => {
    console.log("new message received. ", payload);
    this.currentMessage.next(payload);})
```

You need to trigger the notification  from service worker:

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload) => {
    console.log("new message received. ", payload);
    const NotificationOptions = {
            body: payload.notification.body,
            data: payload.data,
            icon: payload.notification.icon
          }
          navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope').then(registration => {
            registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, NotificationOptions);
          });
    this.currentMessage.next(payload);})
```

Then add in firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
});
```

Comment: Can you tell how to configure the `url` inside of the FCM Legacy HTTP call? Right now, every time a user click on a notification in background, you get redirected to the website but with the path `/undefined`.

Comment: You need to check your payload data. If the data.url was right you should've the right url

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem with my Vue.js application. It's still not clear to me how messaging service works but try to change the input payload.
I suppose you are testing notifications using Postman.

Payload for foreground notifications:

```
{    
  "data":{ ..  },
  "to": "....",
}
```

Payload for background notifications:

```
{
  "notification": { ... },
  "to": ""
}
```

Comment: Can you share your json fields in payload for foreground, also how can you decide when to send the foreground/background notifications?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mafei-dev/angular-fcm-notification-angular8-with-firebase-js-8.3

here is the updated example. please clone and run the project with your configuration details. specially care about the version of the `firebase-app.js` and `firebase-messaging.js` and `@angular/fire` version. as you pointed out example is used very old version of the libraries. in this example, the project has been updated with the new version of the libraries.

`@angular/fire:^6.1.4`
`firebasejs/8.3.1`

especially remove the all code from the `constructor` of `MessagingService` class.

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    )
```

the constructor keeps alone.

```
constructor(){
}
```

it's working...

[image]