# FCM Messaging Issue

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to generate token from FCM by following this [link](https://dev.to/mayurkadampro/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-97a). I am facing issue in `messaging.service`. I couldn't implement `angularFireMessaging.messaging`, its shrowing error in messaging keyword as

> Property 'messaging' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging'

**Code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(  //issue here in messaging
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    )
  }
  requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }
  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      })
  }
}
```

Where I am going wrong please help me out

Comment: check this. there is the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873650/12553450

Answer (score 5):

I think going back to an older version is not an ideal solution. 
I think the author of this question followed a tutorial is a bit out of date.

For the latest version,

```
 this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(  //issue here in messaging
  (_messaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
  }
)
```

is **not required**

Remove everything in the constructor, and update your package.json with the latest version below (at the time of writing this answer)

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
"firebase": "^7.15.1",
```

It will work just fine.

If you'd like to know more details, please follow this official tutorial https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of testing, from [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1iment) which you could find from https://github.com/angular/angularfire#resources

If you go to dependencies:

[image]

You would find out that they used [@angular/fire@5.1.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire/v/5.1.1)

If you're following any tutorial which says you need to do something like:

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
npm install firebase --save
```

You could follow up by using:

```
npm uninstall @angular/fire
npm i @angular/fire@5.1.1 --save
```

Which completely remove any existing installation of @angular/fire and install @angular/fire@5.1.1, and solve the error of

> Property 'messaging' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging'

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove them. The error plainly told you that:

> Property '**messaging**' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging'

From:

```
constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(  //issue here in messaging
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    )
  }
```

Into:

```
constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/messaging/messaging.md

Answer (score 2):

I have it worked with **Angular 8** with next versions

```
npm i firebase@7.6.0 --save
npm i @angular/fire@5.4.0 --save
```

And change version on importScripts

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

appending to @Mykyoo answer, 
make sure you install

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm i firebase@4.6.0 --save
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1338#issuecomment-354249111

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem I run below command:

```
1) decrease the version of @angular/fire from latest to @angular/fire: ^5.2.1
2) use the version of firebase: 7.6.0
```